# Please add TeX rendering in titles on the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, ios-app

I posted a [feature request on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231730/please-add-tex-rendering-in-titles-on-the-ios-app) a couple of days ago concerning TeX support in titles on the SE app on iOS. The reason I posted it there was the fact that MathJax is supported on several SE sites, although not network-wide.

It didn't get much attention though (16 views, 1 up-vote, no comments or answers). I realize I could put a bounty on it, but I estimate that 90 % of the MathJax users reside here and meta.math.SE might therefore be a better place for it.

I'm not sure if this kind of cross-posting is considered bending of the rules. If that's the case, let me know.

Comment: @user147263 Right, I didn't know about the declined Android request.